# Why is Import Statement Failing?

Tags: python, import

I have created a barebones Python program so I can step through the mechanics of using a package library.  Code for my entire program only consists of a few import statements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
```

I'm not experienced with Python.  When I run the code above, I get the following error that is triggered by the 'moveit_commander' import.  Could I be doing something wrong by how I imported the module or should I suspect that something is wrong within the 'moveit_commander' module?

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of
'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_inject    or<boost::lock_error> >'
what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: That looks to me like an error with the underlying dependencies of the `moveit_commander` module.  I would take a look at the module dependencies and try installing them again.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with moveit_commander.

Comment: this is really weird

Comment: `moveit_commander` has several similar issues in its [bug tracker](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_commander/issues). I guess it's safe to say its a problem with the package or how it's installed.